# Keeping Github Forks Private Within an Organization

Tags: github, repository, user-permissions

Let's say I have private repository: **"Product Awesome"**
Now I have 2 teams: **"Reviewers"(2 people)** and **"Contributors"(10 people)**

Now I want all the contributors to work a "Great Feature" **without consulting each other** and come up with the best solution on their own.

So when each of the contributor forks the "Product Awesome" repository, their forks should remain private to each other, *i.e Contributor 5 should not be able to see what is happening in the fork of Contributor 8, All forks should be exclusively private.*

At the same time. All Reviewers should be able to see all the forks. So that they can easily evaluate all the forks.

I am not sure how to get around this.